# Is using some sort of for loop to make a selection the wrong approach in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

For each department, I am trying to find the maximum salary of all of the instructors in a department and then return one table that contains the name of the instructor with the highest salary, their salary and their department name for every single department. Every department should have at least one instructor.

What I have done so far is this:

```
SELECT name, salary, dept_name FROM instructor WHERE salary in 
    (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM dept_name);
```

which is wrong but I am not sure how I can correct it. I am new to SQL, but if this was another programming language I might have done something like this:

```
for each department:
   for each instructor in the department:
       return max salary
```

but I am not sure if this is the correct approach or not.

Here is all of my mysql code:

```
CREATE TABLE department(
    dept_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    building VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    budget DECIMAL(10, 2) UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY(dept_name)
    );

CREATE TABLE instructor(
    ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    dept_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    salary DECIMAL(10, 2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (dept_name) REFERENCES department(dept_name)
    );

insert into instructor values ('10101', 'Srinivasan', 'Comp. Sci.', '65000');
insert into instructor values ('12121', 'Wu', 'Finance', '90000');
insert into instructor values ('15151', 'Mozart', 'Music', '40000');
insert into instructor values ('22222', 'Einstein', 'Physics', '95000');
insert into instructor values ('32343', 'El Said', 'History', '60000');
insert into instructor values ('33456', 'Gold', 'Physics', '87000');
insert into instructor values ('45565', 'Katz', 'Comp. Sci.', '75000');
insert into instructor values ('58583', 'Califieri', 'History', '62000');
insert into instructor values ('76543', 'Singh', 'Finance', '80000');
insert into instructor values ('76766', 'Crick', 'Biology', '72000');
insert into instructor values ('83821', 'Brandt', 'Comp. Sci.', '92000');
insert into instructor values ('98345', 'Kim', 'Elec. Eng.', '80000');

insert into department values ('Biology', 'Watson', '90000');
insert into department values ('Comp. Sci.', 'Taylor', '100000');
insert into department values ('Elec. Eng.', 'Taylor', '85000');
insert into department values ('Finance', 'Painter', '120000');
insert into department values ('History', 'Painter', '50000');
insert into department values ('Music', 'Packard', '80000');
insert into department values ('Physics', 'Watson', '70000');
```

This is using SQL version 5.6

Comment: Please don't edit the question to add unnecessary information. You've stated that every department has at least one instructor, so the department table is redundant in this instance.

Comment: @Strawberry *so the department table is redundant in this instance.* `instructor` table has FK to `department`. OP seems to be afraid to remove both FK and unnesessary table..

Answer (score 2):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT name, 
                     salary, 
                     dept_name, 
                     RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY dept_name ORDER BY salary DESC) rnk 
              FROM instructor )
SELECT name, salary, dept_name
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e1508cebd8eb95c0dfb8ce555c91b14)

If more than one instructor have the same greatest salary within department then all of them will be returned. If you need one of them - use ROW_NUMBER. If you need one definite - update sorting expression also.

> Could you explain how you did that?

`RANK()` function enumerates the rows separately within each department in the ordering by salary decrease (i.e. the row with greatest salary gets the number 1), if some rowsw have the same salary then they obtain the same number. In main query only those rows which number is 1 are selected.

---

For MySQL 5.x you can use

```sql
SELECT t1.name, t1.salary, t1.dept_name
FROM instructor t1
JOIN ( SELECT MAX(salary) salary, dept_name
       FROM instructor
       GROUP BY dept_name ) t2 USING (salary, dept_name);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a5d7bb7c0744f1cdca1a35517d22f597)

Comment: Could you explain how you did that? Also, this does not seem to work with older versions of mySQL. Is there a way I can represent this syntactically so that it is compatible with older versions too?

Answer (score 1):

In general, some sort of loop is probably the wrong approach for solving problems in MySQL.

For older versions of MySQL, and using Akina's fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=852d8257cf11eaa95b4321c1bfeebc23...

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM instructor a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(salary) salary
            , dept_name
         FROM instructor
        GROUP
           BY dept_name
     ) b
    ON b.salary = a.salary
   AND b.dept_name = a.dept_name;
```

Incidentally, this is the most frequently asked question under this tag. There are many correct answers too.